# How can I set the focus inside the Yahoo Rich Text Editor

Tags: javascript, html, richtext

I have a an HTML form which contains the YAHOO rich text editor on it.

When I display the form I want the YAHOO editor to have focus so that the cursor is ready to accept input without the user having to click on it or tab into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this from the documenation over at the [YUI library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui).  Specifically at a sample titled [Editor - Basic Buttons](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/editor_adv_editor.html)

> `var myEditor = new YAHOO.widget.Editor('editor', {focusAtStart:true});`
>   `myEditor.render();`

The key here is the the "focusAtStart" attribute as part of the optional attributes object

Answer (score 0):

I haven't employed the YAHOO rich text editor, but wouldn't it work, if you use a window.onload event ?-)

Answer (score 0):

Like roenving, I have never used the YAHOO rich text editor, but it should work with the `window.onload` event.

Let's say you specified `id="yahoo_text_editor"` for your YAHOO rich text editor.
Then, do

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('yahoo_text_editor').focus()">
```

Hope this helps.